# How to change the color of C# methods in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, colors

Is there a way to change the color of methods in C# in VS 2019? I think the standard yellow they picked for this version is kinda ugly. I tried using the Fonts and Colors options which would be the obvious way to do this, however it doesn't seem to support C# for some reason. Tried changing the color of C++ but didn't change anything.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the option within the Fonts and Colors options one needs to change. It was "User Members - Methods".